# Correct way to access super in completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I have a subclass of NSOperation which send a cancel request over a network. 
I want to cancel operation only if the request was successful :

```
// overrider cancel of NSOperation
-(void)cancel{
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       [super cancel];
    }];
}
```

Will this cause any retain cycle or something ? Do I need a weak Super (I am using ARC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't create a retain cycle, your instance doesn't hold a strong reference to the completion block. However I would prefer not calling the `super` implementation like this, maybe something like this

```
-(void)cancelAfterRequest 
{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
         [self cancel];
    }];
}
```